# Sum of specific elements in list of integers

Tags: python, numpy

I have to write a script for a burnout questionnaire that at the end of the script will give me scores for three subscales. I defined a list with all 22 questions of the questionnaire and a list that stores all answers. Now, I have the list of answers (called `Answerlist`) with 22 values (RatingScale, low = 0, high = 6).
With the numpy library I know how to sum all values

```
total = numpy.sum(Answerlist)
```

What I don't know is how to select the relevant items/questions for each subscale.
I tried

```
subscale1 = numpy.sum(Answerlist[:, [0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 13, 15, 19]])

subscale2 = numpy.sum(Answerlist[:, [4, 9, 10, 14, 21]])
```

but I get the error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`.

Comment: Hello! It looks like `Answerlist` is a `list`, but your treating it like a numpy array. What type do you expect it to have?

Answer (score 0):

If `Answerlist` is a 1D array, then you would index it as follows

```
subscale1 = numpy.sum(Answerlist[[0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 13, 15, 19]])

subscale2 = numpy.sum(Answerlist[[4, 9, 10, 14, 21]])
```

For example

```
>>> data = np.random.randint(0,6,22)
>>> data
array([2, 4, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 5, 3, 3, 1])
>>> data[[1,12,18]]
array([4, 3, 5])
>>> np.sum(data[[1,12,18]])
12
```